# DELETE request to REST API returns 500

Tags: node.js, rest

```
function delete(id, response) {
var https = require('https');
var linkpath = "/v1/endpoint/" + id + "/?token=" + AUTH_KEY;
var req = https.request({
    hostname: 'api.foo.com',
    port: 443,
    path: linkpath,
    agent: false,
    method: 'DELETE',
}, (res) => {
    if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
        response.send('HTTP ' + res.statusCode + ' ' + res.statusMessage);
    }

    res.on('error', function (err) {
        response.send(err);
    });

    res.on('end', function (data) {
        response.send(data);
    });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
    response.send(e.message);
});

req.end();
}
```

This code, adapted from my (working) code that uses a POST request to do other things with this API, nets me a status code of 500 from the endpoint.

I don't know how to debug this. I can't send the URL manually to the server because it's a DELETE operation instead of a GET or POST.

Has anyone seen this problem? Or do you have ideas on how to debug it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postman (https://www.getpostman.com/) is a great tool for manually sending specific HTTP requests, including DELETE!

Comment: Thank you, this showed me the message with the error, which made it clear that I needed to use HTTP, not HTTPS with this endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

There are all sorts of tools that will let you manually send any HTTP to the server. For instance, you can get quite a bit of information with curl, which will happily send a DELETE request.

For example:

```
curl -v -X "DELETE" https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1
```

will return the request and response headers as well as the body of the return value if any.